# Integrating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx }{n^4}$

Tags: calculus, summation, exponential-sum

Consider : $\displaystyle f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx }{n^4}$

Find : $\displaystyle \int_0^{x} f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Can you find $\int_0^x{\sin nt\over n^4}\,dt$?

Comment: If $f_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nt)/n^4$, then $f_N:[0,x]\to\mathbb{R}$ is converges uniformly to $f$ for all $x$. So you can integrate this series term-by-term.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : yes I can but how to calculate this :
$\displaystyle \sum \frac{\cos {nx} }{n^5} $

Comment: @aziiri - if only it were an odd power instead of a power of 4..

Comment: Good question. Fourier series?

Comment: I've tried Fourier series before and failed :
do you know any even function such as :
$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos nt \ \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{n^5} $ 
or just an odd function satisfying the first sum ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - for a Fourier series it would seem that you would need an odd power in the denominator of the sine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that,
$$ \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\ \mathrm dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(nt) \ \mathrm dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\left(  \frac{1}{n}-\frac{\cos(nx)}{n} \right) $$

$$ \implies \int_{0}^{x}f(t) \ \mathrm dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^5}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^5} $$

$$\implies  f(x)=\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx} }{n^5} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-inx} }{n^5} $$

$$ \implies f(x)=\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{2}( \operatorname{Li}_{5}(e^{ix})+ \operatorname{Li}_{5}(e^{-ix}) ),$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)$ is the [Polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: this was my first thought, but I assumed that there is a solution without polylogarithms.

Comment: @aziiri: I do not think you can get it in terms of simpler functions.

Comment: OK, thank you anyway.

Comment: @aziiri: You are welcome.

Comment: @aziiri: By the way, since it was your first thought, why you did not mention it, so we know what we should post.

Comment: I've written what I've done but someone said it is useless, so I deleted it.
sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @aziiri: You do not have to be sorry.